# C++ output readable hex code from serial port

Tags: c, serial-port, hex

I got a little bit of C code here that reads output from a serial device.. I am currently using perl to read the data from the device and that works okay, but I would prefer to write something in C to do the same job.

This is the code I got so far;

```
#include<stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include<unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include<fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include<errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include<termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

char *buf;
int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */
int i,n;

int open_port(void)
{
    fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

if (fd == -1)     {
    perror("cannot open");
}
else
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
struct termios options;
tcgetattr(fd, &options);
cfsetispeed(&options, B38400);
cfsetospeed(&options, B38400);
options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
options.c_cflag |= CS8;
//    options.c_cflag |= (IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // xon & xoff on
return (fd);
}

int main(int argc) {
    buf=malloc(4095);
    open_port();
    free(buf);
    while(1){
        read(fd,buf,128);
         printf("%s\n",buf);
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

When I compile and run it outputs data, but the data I see is in garbage format... what I would like to see is readable hex data like 0AEA4E2A ... anyone has any idea how I can easily transform the data into readable hex code? I have been googling for a while but nothing really seems to do the job.

This is what I did in perl;

```
while ($timeout>0) {
        my ($count,$saw)=$PortObj->read(1); # will read _up to_ 255 chars
        if ($count > 0) {
                $chars+=$count;
                $buffer.=$saw; my $hex = unpack 'H*', $saw; printf ($hex);
```

Comment: Title and tag say C++, you said C. Is this C or C++? Must say it looks like C.

Comment: printf("%x\n",buf); tried this.. but the hex code i get is different from the one i get from perl.. and the perl one is correct..

Comment: what format do you send from perl? char, int, unsigned int? You should read in the same format.

Comment: i mean that if you send a char, you should read a char. In this case i would send unsigned ints and read unsigned ints.

Comment: I added the perl code..

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you want "unified" hex code, padded with zeroes if necessary, and you also want to print **all** the data (the `"%s"` format specifier expects a NUL-terminated string, so if you have zeroes in your binary data, that won't work for sure):

```
read(fd, buf, 128);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
    printf("%02x ", buf[i]);
}
```

You will also want to declare `buf` as `unsigned char *;` and you should also always check the return value of `read()`.

Comment: read the comments in the question, that has been suggested but is not the problem.

Comment: he said he tried but doesnt get the same values back, so i think he has a conversion problem, from perl to c.

Comment: @fonZ 1. `%x` ain't the same as `%02x`, 2. `printf("%x", buf);` has even less relation to `printf("%x", buf[i])` (because he was presumably printing the pointer and not the byte pointed to by the pointer), I know what I am talking about. And yes, I have read the comments.

Comment: @H2CO3 This code gives me something readable.. 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 542 02 4a2 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 5d2 ffffffda2 22 12 f2 702 but it's still a bit off.. I expect to get a 04a5dda..

Comment: @fonZ: There is nothing in the C language that defines any "conversion problems from Perl to C". There is a problem with the C code, and it will have a C solution, and it will have absolutely nothing to do with Perl whatsoever.

Comment: @AlexvanEs: Time to learn how to be precise in your specifications. Are you saying that you want to print 4 bytes at a time, in hexadecimal notation? So go read the documentation for `printf` to find out how to do that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And you came to the rescue when they were offending me. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexvanEs, if you know you want 32bit values, then you could also use the format string "%08x" or "%08X" (my personal preference is upper case, but to each their own).  Also you should decide whether to print the space in the format string, or add it separately (if you want a space that is).